# Add a sheet after available sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add a sheet after total number of sheets available in a workbook.

I declared a variable so user can name new sheet. I have a condition to catch error if user decides not to name it.

```
sheetName = InputBox("Enter new sheet name.")
If sheetName = "" Then
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet    
Else
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name)).Name = sheetName
End If
```

Above code adds a sheet after active sheet.

I have tried replacing

```
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
```

With

```
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name
```

I also tried worksheet object but does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `.Add After:=` you have to specify the Worksheet-Object you want it to add after, not the name. So use:

```vb
Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
```

This adds, every time it is called, a new worksheet at the last position.

If you want to change the Name of the new Worksheet created you could use:

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))

ws.Name = "New Worksheet Name"
```

Comment: @AliZubair When this answers your Question consider accepting the Answer (check mark on the left side of the post). Thanks!